# run .exe file of c++ from matlab with change input value

Tags: c++

I have `a.exe` file that I got from compiling C++ code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I tried to run the `a.exe` file from Matlab, but I put this file to work in loop with another  `.m` file written in Matlab.

The idea is to run the `.m` file in Matlab inside a `for` loop .  First, the Matlab file works with the first value of the loop and after that runs `a.exe` file inside Matlab with the same value and so on. I used `sprintf` to generate string of input for `.exe` file as explained below:

```
wvl=0.4,

for ii=1:100 wvl=0.4+i*0.01;
```

There are another part of Matlab code to do some calculations and prepare input data file for the C++ code:

```
str=sprinf('a.exe,%f',wvl);

system (str);
```

I am already using the command line arguments in C++ code to run the executable file with different values:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

wvl=atof ( argv[1]);
cout << "wvl=" << wvl << endl;
```

The value `wvl` mentioned above I would like to change after compiling the code.

I don't know if the error is in the C++ code or in the Matlab code, because I got the wrong results.

Comment: While you've been a member for quite some time, this looks like your first question. When you post code, you can indent it (look to the orange ? on the edit screen). That makes the code more readable.

Comment: I've tried to format the question into a more readable format. I guess the question boils down to this: _How can I invoke a system executable from within Matlab with arguments?_

Answer (score 0):

Build it as a Matlab EXecutable (MEX) file. It can take input arguments like a Matlab function.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Your question is a little bit ambiguous: You *tried* to run the a.exe, *but* put this file to work?

Comment: thanks for your answer. its not easy to build my c++ code to MEX file.when i compiler my c++ code by Microsoft visual studio 2010 to work without changing the input value in it. its work fine with Matlab code through running by system command.its work fine.

Comment: but i want to change the input in the executable .exe file from matlab

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that you can call .exe files from Matlab with input arguments.

Now I dont't get your question at all. You are able to pass an input from Matlab to your .exe? The .exe takes the input? Then the input is passed to the variable wvl? Or do you want to change the value of the variable wvl after it has come from Matlab?

Maybe that can help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92537-how-do-i-pass-arguments-into-and-out-of-my-standalone-executable

Comment: How did it solve your problem? And what was your problem actually? Please consider upvoting the answers that helped you.